# Is there a way to disable worker dynos on off-hours?

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to disable worker Dynos in between specific hours? I'd like to do this to keep my free dyno hours for a Discord bot, which will not be used between 1:45 AM and 8:30 AM.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has a public API: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference

You can use that API to [update your dyno formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation-batch-update), increasing or decreasing the number of workers.

So, while this isn't offered as an Heroku feature, you can write code which will do it for you. Using [Heroku's Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), you could get a dyno which will run at regular intervals, and decide whether it needs to bring your worker on or off.